# How to create a random 4 digit number and store it as a variable

Tags: python, windows, random

I am working on a guess-the-4-digit-number game in python 2.7.10. But I cannot find how to randomly make a 4 digit number, and store it as a variable. The digit has to be somewhere between 1111 and 9999
The hard part is, that I want to store it as a variable, and not print it out for the player to see.

If you want to, I'll post the code when I'm finished.

The code is finally here!

```
import random
number = random.randint(1111,9999)
tryagain = 'yes'
print ('hello! ')
print ('------------------------------------------------------------- ')
print ('Try and guess the 4 digit number in the least number of tries ')
print ('------------------------------------------------------------- ')
while tryagain == 'yes':
    lowoutput = None
    highoutput = None
    guess = None
    guess = input('Guess: ')
    if guess == number:
        print ('Correct! ')
        correctoutput str(raw_input(Enter 'exit' to exit: "))
        If correctoutput == 'exit':
            print 'Goodbye'
            exit()
        else:
            print 'invalid input'
    elif guess > number:
        print 'Your answer is too high'
        highoutput = str(raw_input("Try again? 'Y'/'N'))
        if highoutput == 'n':
            tryagain = 'n'
        elif highoutput == 'y'
            try again = 'yes'
        else:
            print 'invalid input'
    else:
        print 'Your answer is too low' 
        lowoutput = str(raw_input("Try again 'y'/'n'"))
        if lowoutput == 'n':
            try again = 'n'
        elif lowoutput == 'y'
            tryagain = 'yes'
        else:
            print 'invalid input'
print 'too bad, the right answer was: '
print (number)
exit()
```

This should work. There might be some mistakes cos I wrote this on my tablet. All improvements would be accepted

Comment: `random.randint(1111,9999)` ?

Comment: Yes but I want to store it in a variable

Comment: Ofcourse, thats complicates things alot

Comment: And that's why I'm stuck

Comment: Here - https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers - This should get you started.

Comment: I know the basic programing  and how to get the random number,  I just can't store it in a variable

Comment: I am trying to be as humble as possible when I say this, But when you ask - *how do I store a return value of a function in a variable* - You do not know basic programming - you should really give the link a try.

Comment: Will this work                                                                                                       Import random                                                                                                               r = random.randint(1111,9999)                                                                               will  the variable r be the number?

Comment: Would you like to see the code when I'm finished?

Comment: Yea sure, you can update in the question, for others to see.

Comment: K how do you put it in one of the code box thingies?

Comment: 4 spaces for each code line or just hightlight the complete code and click on the `code` icon on the top.

Comment: the code is finally here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with

```
import random
r = random.randint(1111,9999)
print "%04d" % r
```

or

```
print '{0:04d}'.format(r)
```

Comment: What about numbers `1000` to `1110`?

Comment: I don't want to print it,  I want it to be secret

Comment: @poke because the OP asked  for 1111 to 9999. but you could even do 0 to 9999 and it'll be a 4-digit random due to the format string.